# How to use NER model fine tuned using hugging face transformers with spark nlp on databricks

Tags: apache-spark, nlp, databricks, huggingface-transformers, johnsnowlabs-spark-nlp

I needed to train (fine tune) NER token classifier to recognize our custom tokens.
The easiest way to do that I found was:
[Token Classification with W-NUT Emerging Entities](https://huggingface.co/transformers/custom_datasets.html?highlight=wnut#token-classification-with-w-nut-emerging-entities)

But now I encountered a problem - the plan was to follow:
[HuggingFace in Spark NLP - BERT Sentence.ipynb](https://colab.research.google.com/github/JohnSnowLabs/spark-nlp-workshop/blob/master/jupyter/transformers/HuggingFace%20in%20Spark%20NLP%20-%20BERT%20Sentence.ipynb) ,
but when I try:

```
model.save_pretrained(<path on DBFS>)
```

I get file write error. As far as I understand this is because tranformers/keras won't work on distributed file systems like DBFS

Is there any walkaround for this?

I cannot move training away from databricks because I'm using data (entities) from the database to create training file

PS. Maybe I can do the same using only spark nlp? How- prefarably using same "tag only" format?

Answer (score 3):

You should save the model to the local file system first and then copy it to DBFS:

```py
from distutils.dir_util import copy_tree

local_path = "./tmp/model"
dbfs_path = "/dbfs/tmp/model"

model.save_pretrained(local_path)
copy_tree(local_path, dbfs_path)
```